# I am not able to import Numpy and other packages in Python IDLE (3.8.10) (32 bits)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-import

I have Python 3.8.10. (32 bit). I am trying to import NumPy package in IDLE however I am getting this message.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GoyK.png)

My Idle crashed with following information

```
Problem signature:
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: pythonw.exe
  Application Version:  3.8.10150.1013
  Application Timestamp:    608fe05b
  Fault Module Name:    _multiarray_umath.cp38-win32.pyd
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   6498fabf
  Exception Code:   c000001d
  Exception Offset: 000269c9
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

This same thing happens with other packages like: chainer, matplotlib, pandas, scrapy, Theano. 
But other packages are working fine.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. This problem arises if someone using old system to run NumPy 1.24.0 and onwards.
Simple trick is installed NumPy 1.23.5
For detail: [issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/23731)